# Density of $\lambda_1$ w.r.t. $\lambda_1+\lambda_2$ on $(\mathcal X, \mathcal A)$

Tags: measure-theory

Given non-negative finite measures $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$ on a measurable space $(\mathcal X, \mathcal A)$, what is the density of $\lambda_1$ with respect to $\lambda_1+\lambda_2$?

In other words, can we find a non-negative $\mathcal A$-measurable function $\Delta$ so that $$\lambda_1A=\int_A\Delta(x)d(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)(x)$$ for all $A\in\mathcal A$?

I can see that $(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)A=0\Rightarrow\lambda_1A=0$ for $A\in\mathcal A$, so $\lambda_1\ll\lambda_1+\lambda_2$, but then I am stuck. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Two different questions, both direct from your notes: first, the density is the (class of) function(s) $g$ such that $\lambda_1(A)=\int_Agd(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)$ for every measurable $A$, this is its definition and there is not much more to add to it; second, yes the existence of $g$ is guaranteed, by a theorem called Radon-Nykodym theorem.

Comment: OK thanks, yes: "what is the density" and "does the density exist" are two different questions. I believe you if you tell me there is no obvious form for the (class of) density functions!

Comment: The explicit form of the density depends on the measures $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$.  And in some cases may not be obvious at all.  As @Did correctly pointed out the exsitence of densities is guaranteed by a theorem called Radon-Nykodym theorem.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I am aware the density exists, but I couldn't find it myself. I asked this question just to make sure the answer wasn't obvious. @Did disagreed with my choice of words when I wrote "In other words...", which I included in anticipation of comments like "please define what you mean by a density". So I think we're all on the same page. Thanks again.